# Pull out result by person worked

Tags: impersonation

I Have data set when different person work for different project. Some of project done only one person. Some of project that process by two different person and some of project One person process Tier-1 & Tier-2 level and Tier-3 process other person. Now I would like to some all data by person who work Tier-1, Tier-2 and Tier-3. So can you please guide me that how I can pull out sum data in SQL by person

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EO2L.png)

I need result by person wise total sum of Tier-1, Tier-2, Tier-3